# Sprockets::EncodingError in javascript files in Ruby on Rails3.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, highcharts

I have a **Ruby On Rails(Ruby 1.9; Rails 3.2.13)** application. I am trying to create charts using Highcharts. But i am getting an error on browser as **Sprockets::EncodingError in Product#index**
**sample/app/assets/javascripts/highcharts.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence** .The code files are as below. I have added the files rails.js, highcharts.js and jquery 1.4.2.min.js inside **assets/javascript** folder.

**application.html.erb**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>Sample</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.min", "rails", "highcharts" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     </head>
    <body>

 <%= yield %>
 </body>
</html>
```

The **index.html.erb** file is as below.

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
  </script>
  $(function() {
   new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{
     renderTo:"products_chart" 
     type: 'column'
    }

   title: {
    text: 'Number of Patents Granted',   
   },

 credits: {
  position: {
  align: 'left',
  x: 20
  },
      href: 'http://www.uspto.gov',
  text: 'Source: U.S. Patent & Trademark Office'
  },

 xAxis: {
  categories: [
   '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005',
   '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010',
   '2011' ]
   },

 yAxis: {
    title: {
   text: 'No. of Patents'
    }
 },

 plotOptions: {
 },
   series: [{
    name: 'UK',
    data: [ 4351, 4190, 4028, 3895, 3553,4323, 4029, 3834, 4009, 5038, 4924 ]
    }]

   });
});
```

Can anyone help to resolve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Quick question: is there any particular reason, the JS is in the tempalte and the Js code in the template is not within the `script`-Tags? My first advice would be to separate the JS and or correct the script tags.

Comment: I tried that.. but its still not working. It gives the same error.

Comment: I advice to update ot the newset jquery, secondly which version of Highcharts do you use? Please replace new Highcharts.Chart() with var chart = new Highcharts.Chart();

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The issue is resolved. We need to add the javascript code inside the head section of view and remove
     <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.min", "rails", "highcharts" %> from the application.html.erb file

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Save with Encoding" menu and choose "UTF-8".

In the Sublime Text 2 this is in File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8.